# How to set up subdomains in Apache2?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one web site here `var/www/`; and ~1000 folders here `var/info/subdomain1` `/var/subdomain2`.

Please help to understand How to set up httpd for this right ?

I have this:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName www.spravka-gorod.ru 
    ServerAlias spravka-gorod.ru *.spravka-gorod.ru 
    ServerSignature Off
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spravka-gorod\.ru [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://$1.spravka-gorod.ru/$2 [R=301,L]

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/%1
    ErrorLog /var/log/spravka-gorod.ru/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/spravka-gorod.ru/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews ExecCGI
    UseCanonicalName Off
</virtualhost>
```

And all what I got is access for `/var/subdomain1` like my `subdomain1.domain.ru` 
but I need have `/var/info/subdomain1` ...2 ...3 etc.

Comment: Have you tried `VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/%1"` for grabbing the subdomain name? Pretty sure it needs quotes.

Comment: The subdomain dirs. are in `/var` or `/var/info`?

Comment: in /var/info - And it's main problem form me ... because I got it worked in /var but can't adjust for /var/info ...